# How do i retrieve images from folder which is linked to an item id?

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

The main issue is with the model, i cant figure out how to join the two tables so that i can display an item with its image  which are stored in different locations.
model

```
         $this->db->select('bs_items.id, bs_items.description, bs_items.title, 
         bs_items.touch_count,bs_items.price');
         $this->db->from('core_images');
         $this->db->join('bs_items', 'core_images.img_parent_id = 
         bs_items.id');
         $this->db->order_by('bs_items.touch_count', 'desc');
         $this->db->from('bs_items');
```

Controller:

```
            this->load->model('Popular_car');
            $this->load->model('Recent_car');
            $data['popular_cars']= $this->Popular_car->popular_car();
            $data['recent_cars']=$this->Recent_car->get_listing();
            $this->load->view('templates/header');
            $this->load->view('pages/home', $data);
            $this->load->view('pages/home_recent', $data);
            $this->load->view('templates/footer');
```

Comment: Did you stored the image in a directory ?

Comment: yes, the images are stored in a directory.

Comment: The images are stored in a directory, the database contains the image path and image parent ID (which is the ID of the item). I would like to display the item together with its image.

Comment: Please share some code, or database structure. Basically what you want to do is pretty easy. Just create a model that retrieves the data from the database and send it to the controller. Then that controller should send the data to the view. The view will iterate the content and show every content and respective image.

Comment: Please update your question with what you've tried so far, stack overflow is not free code writing service

Answer (score 0):

Please update your question with some code you have done , or ***database structure***. i'm giving you the answer based on what i understood using your given code snippet.

**Model**

```
function get_items()
{
     $this->db->select('*');
     $this->db->from('core_images');
     $this->db->join('bs_items', 'core_images.img_parent_id = 
     bs_items.id');
     $this->db->order_by('bs_items.touch_count', 'desc');
     $query = $this->db->get();
     return $query->result();
}
```

**Controller**

```
function get_allitems() 
{ 
     $this->load->model('model_name');
     $data['items'] = $this->model_name->get_items(); 
     $this->load->view('view_name', $data); 
}
```

**View**

```
<?php foreach ($items as $row): ?> 

   <h1><?php echo $row->title;?></h1>
   <p><?php echo $row->touch_count;?></p>
   <p><?php echo $row->price;?></p>
   <p><?php echo $row->description;?></p>
   <img src="<?php echo base_url().'path_of_image/'.$row->image_from_db; ?> 

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

$myString = $this->db->get_where('profile_table' , array('id' => $edit ) )->row()->file_name_galery;

// $json11 = '{ "1":"s1.jpg", "2":"s2.jpg", "3":"s4.jpg", "4":"s4.jpg", "5":"s5.jpg" }';
    $array = json_decode($myString);

```
if (empty($array)) {
    echo '<p class="tx-danger"> NO IMAGE..</p>';
}         
foreach($array as $key => $photo) { <div class="column_galery text-center zoom_img_app"> 
        <a  onclick="selected_photo('  echo $photo;  ')" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit_image_mod" > 
            <img class=""   src="http://yourapp.com/uploads/profile_gallery/  echo $photo;  " style="width:100%"> <span  class="tx-danger">DELETE</span> </a>
        </div> }
```